# Failed tests while testing scikit-learn install by means of nose

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following error while testing scikit-learn install by means of nose:

```
ERROR: sklearn.utils.tests.test_sparsefuncs.test_densify_rows
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\tests\test_sparsefuncs.py",
line 40, in test_densify_rows
    assign_rows_csr(X, rows, np.arange(out.shape[0])[::-1], out)
  File "sparsefuncs.pyx", line 300, in sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.assign_rows_csr
 (sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs.c:4029)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'npy_intp' but got 'long'
```

I guess my question is if this a minor issue and can be easily disregarded?

Environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Python 3.3

Command: nosetests sklearn --exe

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the only failure? In any case, it can only hurt the minibatch k-means algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20130801045732.GB12916%40phare.normalesup.org&forum_name=scikit-learn-general. It seems not to be a (big) problem. To quote the relevant part

> This is good news. The problems are fairly minor. Don't worry about the
>   issue. These tests failing are numerically unstable ones. We'll see what
>   we can do about them, but they are not release blockers. The good news is
>   that we don't have major building or linking problem.

One of the tests that is failing in the above link is the same test that is failing for you.

Comment: Missed that one. Thanks